# Setting up VPN on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I am trying to make my Ubuntu Server (16.04) run behind a VPN. I have a subscription to NordVPN and have followed their procedure to connect to the VPN via OpenVPN - it successfully connects.

I then use Screen to continue running OpenVPN in the background, and when I try to check the servers external IP or ping google.com it fails as if there is no connection to the VPN. I have tried multiple VPN servers.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
**ifconfig**

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:b3:cc:df:31:91
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2b3:ccff:fedf:3191/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2190765 errors:0 dropped:16 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2347458 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2100301066 (2.1 GB)  TX bytes:1710956391 (1.7 GB)
          Interrupt:18

> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:132225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:132225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:37777958 (37.7 MB)  TX bytes:37777958 (37.7 MB)

> tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.7.7.242  P-t-P:10.7.7.241  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:21997 (21.9 KB)  TX bytes:62173 (62.1 KB)
```

Tried to ping google.com - failed to get a response.

downloading a file with wget get:

> wget: unable to resolve host address

ping 8.8.8.8:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=404 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=370 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=369 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=369 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 time=404 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=48 time=369 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 369.680/381.456/404.838/16.344 ms
```

**EDIT 2:**
**dig a google.com @8.8.8.8:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> a google.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15859
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.         203     IN      A       216.58.216.238

;; Query time: 388 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 31 15:00:37 AEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: For assistance, you will need to provide your network configuration and actual tests.  Does `ping 8.8.8.8` get replies?  If not, show us your routing table (`route -n`) while connected.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thanks for the response. I have added ifconfig, wget and the ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Can you show the output of `dig a google.com @8.8.8.8`?

Comment: By the way, as you can see, multi-line quotes don't show line feeds so you should show them as code.

Comment: @JuliePelletier put settings in code blocks and added the dig a google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to get everything working is to set up your local DNS settings properly.

The simplest way to do it is to put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` after backing it up (`mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. If you don't mind, why did that work setting the DNS to Googles? What did the "dig a google.com @8.8.8.8" tell you.

Comment: It was actually already obvious when you were able to ping 8.8.8.8 that you could use it for your DNS but I wanted to make sure there was nothing blocking it.  `dig` is a DNS query tool.